# Autoresize not working in Storyboard App

Tags: ios, storyboard, xcode6, autoresize

This is very new for me.. there is Custom calendar library DSLCalendarView on Github,
the problem is that when I try to use it in My storyboard app then it is not resize view for iPhone 6 and plus But strangely when I'm running demo of downloaded Github App then it is actually Fit to screen size for iPhone 6 and plus size phone.

I used there files as it is in my project..But not sure what goes wrong ?
I also did use that customView in xib Controller rather than storyboard But same issue appears.

[image: following autoresize mask i add to the view which is exactly same as in there demo app]

above autoresize mask i add to the view which is exactly same as in there demo app
Okay I'm adding screenshot to explain my problem

[image: This is screen shot of Github downloaded project in iPhone 6 simulator]

This is screen shot of Github downloaded project in iPhone 6 simulator

[image: and this is for my project screenshot in which it is resize the view]

and this is for my project screenshot in which it is resize the view

Comment: What constraints have you added to that view?

Comment: HI @picciano.. I added the autoresize mask in question now for Xib and same for storyboard..!

Comment: What is the problem exactly, there's not enough information to understand what you expected and how it actually worked for you. I even downloaded the sample app only to find out that it doesn't have any special resizing going on, the view `DSLCalendarView ` seems to scale just like any other `UIView` would.

Comment: @A-Live thanks for response and yes I updated the Question now Please have a look. I added the Images now to understand properly.

Comment: Dunno where you taken this example from, the latest [commit](https://github.com/PeteC/DSLCalendarView) doesn't have any top title view, neither it shows calendar full-screen with iPhone 6 simulator. Anyway, in this situation it is important to check the initial frame of the view at IB, not only its resizing mask. Also, if you select Attributes Inspector of the top-level VC view you can *simulate* different sizes on the go, from what I can see it should work for this view.

Comment: @A-Live thanks.. there is discussion on github https://github.com/PeteC/DSLCalendarView/issues/35 for the same problem.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just linking the answer .. As I got it from Github forum [DSLCalendarView issues](https://github.com/PeteC/DSLCalendarView/issues/35)

Answer (score 0):

Try this in ViewDidLoad

```
dlCalanderView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleWidth
```

Comment: thks.. I did tried that but no use same issue is there.